# Superfish + Cufon Hover

Tags: jquery, cufon, superfish

For this wordpress-site: http://bit.ly/NlBv9I I use sliding doors for the rounded corners and cufon for the font. 
When I wanted to add a dropdown-menu, I ran into a problem with the hover of the "diensten"-tab. When I left the sub-menu through the bottom of the submenu my main-item wouldn't go back to normal styling. With the superfish onHide function I managed to fix this, but now when I hover out the main item to the submenu, the main item's color changes to the background color (so it becomes invisible). I tried to fix this with the onBeforeShow function and that works, but that breaks my first solution.

You can find the HTML here: http://bit.ly/NlBv9I

CSS:

```
ul {
    list-style:none;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
}

#main-nav li {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 2px;
    display: block;
}

#main-nav li a {
    color:#6f6f6f;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 4px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#main-nav li.sfHover a {
    color:#fff;
}
#main-nav li:hover a, #main-nav li.current_page_item a, #main-nav li.current-menu-item a {
    color:#fff;
}
#main-nav li a:hover, #main-nav li.current_page_item a, #main-nav li.current-menu-item a {
    background: url(img/leftDoor.png) top left no-repeat;
}
#main-nav li:hover, #main-nav li.current_page_item, #main-nav li.current-menu-item {
    background: url(img/rightDoor.png) top right no-repeat;
}
#main-nav ul li.sfHover, #main-nav ul li.sfHover li  {
    background: url(img/rightDoor.png) top right no-repeat;
}
#main-nav ul li.sfHover a {
    background: url(img/leftDoor.png) top left no-repeat;
}
#main-nav ul.sub-menu a {
    color:#fff;
}
#main-nav .grey {
    color:#6f6f6f !important;
}
#main-nav .white {
    color:#fff !important;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$('#top .menu').superfish({
                    hoverClass:    'sfHover',
                autoArrows: false,
                delay:0,
                /*onBeforeShow: function() { $(this).prev().addClass('white'); },*/
                onHide: function() { $(this).prev().addClass('grey') }
            });
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use

```
Cufon.refresh();
```

When you are using `Cufon font` you need to use `Cufon.refresh()` after you change any style, say, you have used `addClass('gray')` and that class applies `gray color` to the font but if you don't use `Cufon.refresh()` after you change the class then you can't see the change. In other words, after changing the font style of any element dynamically that are using `Cufon font` you have to use `Cufon.refresh();` to take effect.