# Script works fine in JSfiddle but not on site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on the ability to show/hide div's when an image is clicked and to randomly show divs on page load.  I'm not quite sure why it works in the testing area (JSfiddle) but not when I implement it into the site.

Here a link to the fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/JmVUx/17/

And here's a demo to the site I am working on:  http://sjdunham.com/test/yzn/

Am I missing something?  Not too sure what could be the difference between the two.  I've tried stripping out any other references to other scripts and still no go.  There are no errors that I can see on the demo site in the inspector.  I've been staring at this for the past 4 hours and I have no idea what could be causing the issue.

Comment: try adding `type="text/javascript"` in that script tag

Comment: `$('.hider:visible')` returns `[]` in site.

Comment: Attempt that `console.log(randomIndex);` is always printing 1 when run in site.

Answer (score 3):

You have other `<a>` elements on the site. Use `$("a.control")` instead, and use `.eq` instead of `$($(...).get(x))`.

Comment: DAP! it was the a.control.

And should it be:
var field = .eq.data('field');

Answer (score 0):

I've checked both of your codes and see that there's something smoothly different:

```
var randomIndex = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1)%2; // Site version
var randomIndex = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100)+ 1)%3;  // jsFiddle version
```

Check everything out again. Maybe you get the answer.
It should be random with both implementations, but it may not be random enough. What I mean is: it can be resulting much of the same randomIndex, so you cannot check the difference when loading page.

Comment: Oh, crap.  Yeah, I forgot to adjust that on the site version.  Overall there will be 5 items to randomize so I know I'll have to change that to 5.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `Cufon font` and after any changes to `dom` that are using `Cufon font` needs to be refreshed to take affect using `Cufon.refresh();` so add this line at last of your code, i.e.

```
// other code
$('#' + field + '-gallery, #' + field + '-tag').fadeIn("slow");
Cufon.refresh(); // without this line your dom won't refresh (only for cufon font)
```

All of your content in the `p` replaced with `cufon` like below code because of `Cufon.replace(...)`

```
<p>
    <cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="In " style="width: 20px; height: 16px; ">
        <canvas width="33" height="16" style="width: 33px; height: 16px; top: 0px; left: 0px; "></canvas>
        <cufontext>In </cufontext>
    </cufon>
    <cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="today's " style="width: 65px; height: 16px; ">
        <canvas width="78" height="16" style="width: 78px; height: 16px; top: 0px; left: 0px; "></canvas>
       <cufontext>today's </cufontext>
   </cufon>
   ....
</p>
```

[**Another answer on so**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11475807/superfish-cufon-hover/11477214#11477214).

Comment: Yeah, I've been running into that issue now.  Seems to be breaking the gallery when the page is reloaded and you click on one of the images to reveal the other gallery.